# Will PDT change to PST in winters?

Tags: java

I intended to display time in PST zone. I found a format which embeds the time zone PDT with the time but I want to know if this will change to PST during winters.

This is how the code looks like now.

```
public static final String OUTPUT_FORMAT_STD_DATE6_TIMEZONE = "MM/dd/yy hh:mm a z";

public static String convertUTC( String strDate, String inputFormat, String outputFormat ) {
    String displayDateString = null;

    try {
        DateFormat inFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( inputFormat );
        inFormat.setTimeZone( TimeZone.getTimeZone( "UTC" ) );
        Date date = inFormat.parse( strDate );

        DateFormat outFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( outputFormat );
        outFormat.setTimeZone( TimeZone.getDefault() );

        displayDateString = formatDate(date, outputFormat);
    } catch ( ParseException pe ) {
        log.error( "DateUtil.convertUTC :Parse exception while parsing,"+strDate+" using format :"+inputFormat) ; 
    }

    return displayDateString;
}

public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
    if( EVENT.equalsIgnoreCase( qName ) ) {
        auditEntries.add(entry);
    } else if( LOG_TIME.equalsIgnoreCase( qName ) ) {
        String time = content.toString();
        entry.setLogTime( DateUtils.convertUTC(time, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", DateUtils.OUTPUT_FORMAT_STD_DATE6_TIMEZONE));
}
```

Time shows up as follows:

```
06/09/17 07:44 AM PDT
```

Comment: Change the time on your OS and find out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display it always in PST zone then you can use the below rather than using the default.

```
TimeZone.getTimeZone("PST")
```

I am assuming that you just did not try changing your system's time because it runs on a server. Whether or not it changes would depend on your server's configuration if the timezone of the JVM running the application has not been expplicitly overridden by JVM flags. So the answer is it depends on where the code runs. Better be explicit in case you always want to display time in PST.